# Create draft version while doc is pending

Tags: versioning, content-approval, draft

I need to allow users to keep working on their documents while they are waiting for approval on them. ie I want to be able to approve the latest pending version while there are newer drafts on top of it.

I'm using minor/major versioning and approval. I can see why you would not normally want to let people keep developing something that is not yet approved, but in this case we are using the approval process to involve the team rather than actually control content. We jointly decide to publish, so that we have buy in from the entire team to stand up for our results.

Any thoughts appreciated, thanks

anders